# How to upload configuration files using the shell provider?

Tags: files, vagrant, upload, provisioning

Apart from installing applications like emacs on my guest machine, I would also like to upload some configuration files (e.g. to configure emacs for Clojure development). Sadly, Vagrant's documentation gives no clue about how to do this. I guess I'd have to put the configuration files into a shared folder and then copy them from the shared folder on the guest machine to the desired locations?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the "file" provisioner. It seems to be undocumented, but usage is simple. For example:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  # ...

  config.vm.provision :file do |file|
    file.source      = '~/.my.conf'
    file.destination = '/home/vagrant/.my.conf'
  end
end
```

First catch is that it is run as the ssh user ("vagrant" by default) without sudo, so you need to have write access to the directory on the VM. A workaround is to copy to a temporary location and then use a normal shell provisioner to copy/move it to right place.

Second issues is that target paths are not expanded correctly. So using `~` or `$HOME` most probably won't work as expected. (The source path on the other hand *is* expanded.)

Comment: Vagrant 1.5 will expand also the target paths on most guest platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should "put the configuration files into a shared folder and then copy them from the shared folder on the guest machine to the desired location".